# How can I make this statement converted to eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, slim

How can I make this statement converted to eloquent?

```sql
(SELECT conversations_id
FROM conversation_users
WHERE users_id = $myid)
INTERSECT
(SELECT conversations_id
FROM conversation_users
WHERE users_id = $recipientid)
```

The result should be this:
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it yet. But you can try something like this. This query may be needed some adjustment.

```
$q1 = DB::table('conversation_users')->where('users_id', $myid);
$q2 = DB::table('conversation_users')->where('users_id', $recipientid);

DB::select($q1->toSql().' intersect '.$q2->toSql(), array_merge($q1->getBindings(), $q2->getBindings()));
```

Comment: im not sure if this is considered Eloquent since this is just the query builder